# split string in C different variables

Tags: c, strtok, strcpy

I have a string like:

```
char string = " dog beans 1234 cat rice 0123 bird peanut 7777"
```

I would like split that in different variables like:

```
char animals[1000], food[1000], numbers[1000];
```

What I did until now:

```
int i;
while (string != NULL)  {
    for (i = 0, i < 1000, i++) {
        strcpy(animals[i], strtok(string, " ");
        strcpy(food[i], strtok(string, " ");
        strcpy(numbers[i], strtok(string, " ");
    }
}
```

The first loop is working fine, but the second one throws a segmentation fault.

Comment: Your code won't compile.  The calls such as `strcpy(animals[i], strtok(string, " ");` are missing a `)` before the semicolon.  (And `char string = "…";` doesn't compile either! Beware of making it `char *string` because then you're hacking a string literal — not good)  Please don't post code that does not compile (unless you are seeking help for a compilation error) — it annoys people.

Comment: It would be helpful, too, if you showed what you wanted as output.  If you want the `animals` array to hold `"dog cat bird"` and the `numbers` array to hold `"1234 0123 7777"`, you do things one way.  If you want arrays of pointers, then you do things another way.  It also helps if you create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Clearly, this is not a copy of the code you're running because it can't compile.

Answer (score 2):

First, you are treating `animals`, `food`, and `numbers` as an array of strings, but you declare them as arrays of characters. You need to declare them as arrays of `char` arrays, or as arrays of `char` pointers, in which case you would need to allocate the strings with `malloc`.

```
char animals[100][20];
char food[100][20];
char numbers[100][20];
```

Second, when you call `strtok` with the same non-null initial parameter, you will get the same value. You need to pass `NULL` in all invocations after the initial one:

```
strcpy(animals[i], strtok(string, " "));
strcpy(food[i], strtok(NULL, " "));
strcpy(numbers[i], strtok(NULL, " "));
```

Comment: After the first iteration of the outer loop, the second iteration needs the first `strtok()` to use `NULL`, not `string`.

Answer (score 0):

First, as you read up to 1000 animal names, you require `1000` elements of `animal[99]` (assuming a single animal name has a max length of 99) instead of "one animal name of size 1000 for all".

Second, your `strtok` will always start from the initial string, always yielding the same value `dog`. Use `string` only for the first call, and `NULL` for all the other ones.

Note further that `strtok` will return `NULL` if it cannot extract another token; this could happen also within the loop, such that, for example, a `strcpy(food[i], strtok(...))` might crash. Hence, I'd suggest to check the return value of `strtok` before further usage:

```
char animals[1000][99];
char food[1000][99];
char numbers[1000][99];
int  i=0;
char *token = strtok(string, " ");
while (i < 1000 && token)
  strcpy (animals[i], token);
  token = strtok(NULL, " ");
  if (!token) 
    break;
  strcpy (food[i], token);
  token = strtok(NULL, " ");
  if (!token) 
    break;
  strcpy (numbers[i], token);
  token = strtok(NULL, " ");
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Vast improvement on the original code, but still unsafe use of `strcpy`.